# php xml xpath how to extract desired match

Tags: php, xml

I have question on how to access SourceUrl for image with width=400

images/di/47/6b/77/454430384d6d324b413332544a695675313851-400x400-0-0.jpg?p=p2.7f19fe93a466ae45afab&a=1&c=1&l=7000610&r=1&pr=1&lks=43998&fks=35198

By default it is showing me image with width=100 and somehow my xpath syntax is not picking  up 400

```
  <?php
$string = <<<XML
<imageList>
<image available="true" height="100" width="100">
        <sourceURL>images/di/47/6b/77/454430384d6d324b413332544a695675313851-100x100-0-0.jpg?p=p2.7f19fe93a466ae45afab&a=1&c=1&l=7000610&r=1&pr=1&lks=43998&fks=35198</sourceURL>
</image>
<image available="true" height="200" width="200"><sourceURL>images/di/47/6b/77/454430384d6d324b413332544a695675313851-200x200-0-0.jpg?p=p2.7f19fe93a466ae45afab&a=1&c=1&l=7000610&r=1&pr=1&lks=43998&fks=35198</sourceURL></image>
<image available="true" height="300" width="300"><sourceURL>images/di/47/6b/77/454430384d6d324b413332544a695675313851-300x300-0-0.jpg?p=p2.7f19fe93a466ae45afab&a=1&c=1&l=7000610&r=1&pr=1&lks=43998&fks=35198</sourceURL></image>
<image available="true" height="400" width="400"><sourceURL>images/di/47/6b/77/454430384d6d324b413332544a695675313851-400x400-0-0.jpg?p=p2.7f19fe93a466ae45afab&a=1&c=1&l=7000610&r=1&pr=1&lks=43998&fks=35198</sourceURL></image>
<image available="true" height="569" width="500"><sourceURL>images/di/47/6b/77/454430384d6d324b413332544a695675313851-500x569-0-0.jpg?p=p2.7f19fe93a466ae45afab&a=1&c=1&l=7000610&r=1&pr=1&lks=43998&fks=35198</sourceURL></image></imageList>
XML;


$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); 

$result = $xml->xpath("//image[@height='400']/sourceURL");



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is all right, but **the XML is not valid**, see http://www.xmlvalidation.com
The `&` within your links will be parsed as start of a character entity --> error.

**solution**: exclude the text within `<sourceURL>` from parsing with `<![CDATA[...]]>`:

```
$x = <<<XML
<imageList>
<image available="true" height="100" width="100">
    <sourceURL>
        <![CDATA[images/di/47/6b/77/454430384d6d324b413332544a695675313851-100x100-0-0.jpg?p=p2.7f19fe93a466ae45afab&a=1&c=1&l=7000610&r=1&pr=1&lks=43998&fks=35198]]>
    </sourceURL>
</image>
...
</imageList>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);
$result = $xml->xpath("//image[@height='400']/sourceURL")[0];
echo $result;
```

**output**:

```
images/di/47/6b/77/454430384d6d324b413332544a695675313851-400x400-0-0.jpg?p=p2.7f19fe93a466ae45afab&a=1&c=1&l=7000610&r=1&pr=1&lks=43998&fks=35198
```

**see it working**: http://codepad.viper-7.com/31PLr3

**more on CDATA**: [What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)